# I cannot find Participant Count and Max Participants in Edit Price option for price sets WordPress

Tags: wordpress, price-sets

In Drupal, I have the option in a price set, price option to limit the number of people who can book at a certain price.

I do not see this option in a wordpress install (civi version 5.13)

Do I need to turn this option on somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

My mistake.. I had configured the price set as a contribution, not an event fee.